# add class to all the elements having selected name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created prices tab now on the top I have created tabs and at bottom there are list items of different packages standard standard plus etc so when user selects first package 3 out of 6 items are visible and other are hidden so when user clicks second 4 or may be 5 items in the list are visible and rest are hidden same goes for the third package the problem is that I have able to working n it to make it easy rather then making 3 different div's to show all 3 packages I kept it to same and made list items and on every list item I have placed attribute I want when user click on any tab it will get the attribute name and find that attribute within the list and add's the active class to that I item make sense ? I have working on it for the past many days but unable to find the solution for it can anyone help me out with this concern.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/90mynos3/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I see 2 issues with your code.

First you're never removing the active class, so once it's active, it will never be reset. Adding this at the beginning will remove the visible class.

```
$('li.visible').removeClass('visible');
```

Second, in order to add the class, you must target the correct elements, to do this, you can use an attribute selector:

```
$('li[data-clean-group~="' + get_class + '"]').addClass('visible');
```

Using the `~=` operator will match `li` elements with a `data-clean-group` that contains the full word in get_class, preventing `standard` from matching `standard_plus`

See the [this fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cj7244h/) for a working example and [this lesson](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) on attribute selectors for more details on using attribute selectors.